# Any way to remove Totem but still have video thumbnails in Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, vlc, totem, thumbnails

I prefer to use VLC because it never gives me problems while Totem does. I'd like to uninstall Totem, so all file associations point to VLC. However I still want to have video thumbnails in Nautilus.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get remove totem`?

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't solve the "still have video thumbnails in Nautilus" part :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not actually uninstalling it but if you do `sudo cp /usr/share/applications/totem.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/totem.desktop` and then `gedit ~/.local/share/applications/totem.desktop` and add a new line `Hidden=true` the desktop will completely forget totem exists. It will no longer be used for file associations and will not show up in the menus but the thumbnailer should continue to function.

Comment: This works for me, I wanted to uninstall totem mostly because I didn't know of a better way to completely remove it from the file associations.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to leave the [totem-common](http://packages.ubuntu.com/totem-common) package installed. You can remove all of the other totem packages and still have thumbnails.

After that check the preview tab in nautilus preferences
[image: Nautilus Preferences Dialog]

As you can see I have everything set to local and anything over 10MB won't get one. Meaning most videos apart from a few family videos. You can change this up to 4GB.

If you have changed this and still no joy, then try deleting your `~/.thumbnails` folder. Go to your home folder and press ctrl+h to show the hidden files and folders. After this log out or restart nautilus and after a few minutes it should start to rebuild the thumbnail cache (ps good way to get some drive space back). If this doesn't work or nothing happens hours after restarting nautilus then a re-installation of Nautilus may be required. To do this open Synaptic package manager and search for `nautilus` right click on the checkmark next to the package and select re-install from the menu.

Comment: totem-common seems installed even after I remove totem but still no thumbnails. Here's the output from the console:

`sudo apt-get remove totem
...
sudo apt-get install totem-common 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
totem-common is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.`

Answer (score -1):

Try installing ffmpeg thumbnailer.